# How to extract lines that are within radius of cartesian coordinates

Tags: bash

I have a data file that has the format of the following:

```
ATOM      4  N   ASP A   1     105.665  49.507  41.867  1.00 71.64           N  
ATOM      5  CA  ASP A   1     105.992  48.589  42.982  1.00 70.20           C  
ATOM      6  C   ASP A   1     107.024  49.191  43.936  1.00 69.70           C
```

In row 1 the numbers (105.665, 49.507, and 41.867) are the columns of the coordinates (x,y,z). How do I extract the entire line with coordinates that are within a specified radius and output them in another file? The equation to correlate the coordinates to the radius is:

radius= SQRT(x^2 + y^2 +z^2)

Comment: You seem to be working on a PDB structure. If you have any experience with Python, you could use one of the available packages to do that work for you! To my knowledge there's [MDAnalaysis](https://github.com/MDAnalysis/mdanalysis/) and [mdtraj](https://github.com/mdtraj/mdtraj).

Comment: Please update the file properly. The values `105.314, 50.822, and 41.951` are not there in the sample lines shown. Also what is the radius value to check against?

Comment: How do we check if the computed radius is within a limit? Update the question with proper details

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you mean this:

```
awk -v R=124.44 '($7^2)+($8^2)+($9^2) < R^2' YourFile
```

Change the `R=124.44` to match your radius.

**Sample Output**

```
ATOM      4  N   ASP A   1     105.665  49.507  41.867  1.00 71.64           N  
ATOM      5  CA  ASP A   1     105.992  48.589  42.982  1.00 70.20           C
```